# How did Li know that Po was alive end of Kung-fu Panda 2?

Tags: kung-fu-panda

At the very end of Kung-fu Panda II, they show Po's father Li Shan living in the new Panda village in the mountains and Li Shan says out loud "My son is alive", seemingly coming out of nowhere.

How does he know this?  As far as I can tell, it's never explained.

Did word of a Panda saving China reach him?   Did he realize it through meditation, cause it looked like he might have been meditating prior to the realization cause he was alone and a bit away from the Village.

Was it ever explained?